# Open a URL in bootstrap modal dialog box

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

Hi friends I am working on an Angular project using bootstrap for designing. How can I open a HTTPS URL in a bootstrap modal dialog box?

Problem:

On button click I open a modal dialog box and in that I want to open a URL such as "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask". Can anyone help me with its TS and HTML code?

HTML CODE:

```html
    <div id="videoPreview" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="closeModal()" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div> </div> </div>
```

Summary:
    The modal dialog box is working fine. A blank white modal dialog box appears on button click with small cross icon on right side, just that i want to open a new page with a url in this dialog box

Comment: use iframe.

<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

Comment: i guess iframe is for youtube videos. i want to open a different page in that modal

Comment: no, its nothing like that, iframe is use for opening urls in a container, check given example.

<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

Comment: ok, i moved one step forward with this. Dialog box opens but the url opened in that dialog box is my project localhost url

Comment: can you please share sample code now ?

Comment: oh thanku so much , i got what i wanted its working fine now, thnku

Comment: hi piyush i generally have some ques in angular and you were very helpful, so if you would like to connect here's my email id: surbhi@coffeebeanstechnologies.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  for that or ajax if you got third Party API